# Is it possible to check the DNS server you're using on the iphone?

Tags: ios, dns

on windows, you'd use something like ipconfig /all to see the dns server you're hitting.

What would u do on an iphone or mobile device?

Answer (score 4):

You can see the DNS assigned to the Wi-Fi in **Settings → Wi-Fi**, then tapping on the blue arrow next to the network you're connected to. I'm not sure if it's possible to do the same for the cellular connection however.

Comment: ah that's useful. but yeah, it would be good to be able to do it for 3G too

Comment: I would like to ask a follow up question. So if Settings->WiFi->DNS is configured as "Automatic", then which DNS server is used? The one defined in the WiFi router? IP address?